# User can open same application in more than two tabs in same browser

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an N2 project, and one bug arose.

In N2 software the user can open the same application more than two times in the same browser.  How can I solve this problem?

I want the user to only be able to open the N2 application once in the same browser.  If the user logs in with the same or different user id in the N2 software with the same browser then display a message box.

I am a junior developer, so please provide full details.

Comment: There's no way to do this. The user will always be able to open up a second tab and load your page twice. However, if you give us some context related to the problem that this causes, we might be able to help you find a better solution.

Comment: Normally, this isn't something you want to prevent.  Generally speaking, users have a very good reason for opening multiple browser windows for the same site.  One example is to be able to view multiple accounts side by side.  Usually you want to encourage this behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Each tab in a browser represents the same browser instance.  Browser's manage session by each browsers instance.  You can't control session per tab, only by browser instance ie:SessionID.  You will find some solutions that try to solve this but there are always holes, because of the fundamental way browser handle tabs.

You are likely to cause more problems trying to prevent this rather than just educating your users.

Comment: Or instead of trying to educate them, just make sure that you application handles more than one instance running.

Comment: Even if your app handles more than one instance, which it should, the user has to understand why opening multiple tabs doesn't create new sessions.